# Python: ValueError: Can't handle mix of unknown and binary

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am using confusion_matrix from sklearn and i have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 363, in <module>
    confusionMatrix = confusion_matrix(Yt , Yint)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 240, in confusion_matrix
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 82, in _check_targets
    "".format(type_true, type_pred))
ValueError: Can't handle mix of unknown and binary
```

my code:

```
for accuracyt in range(len(inputMappingTest)):
    if Y[accuracyt] > 0:
        Yint[accuracyt] = 1
    else:
        Yint[accuracyt] =- 1

Yt = numpy.asarray(Yt)
confusionMatrix = confusion_matrix(Yt , Yint)
```

what should i do? thank you.

Comment: Show some samples of your data, X and Y and also why are you manually setting values in Yint to 1, -1. The algorithm used will do it.

Comment: I have edited your code to a reasonable indentation, but please try to format your own code so that it can actually be run when copy-and-pasted.

Comment: You need to provide more detail, please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: can you please ellaborate more about your problem ... may be I can help